# python matplotlib filled boxplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, boxplot

Does anyone know if we can plot filled boxplots in python matplotlib?
I've checked http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html but I couldn't find useful information about that.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html ?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The example that @Fenikso shows an example of doing this, but it actually does it in a sub-optimal way.

Basically, you want to pass `patch_artist=True` to `boxplot`.

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 1000) for std in range(1, 6)]
plt.boxplot(data, notch=True, patch_artist=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you'd like to control the color, do something similar to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 1000) for std in range(1, 6)]

box = plt.boxplot(data, notch=True, patch_artist=True)

colors = ['cyan', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen', 'tan', 'pink']
for patch, color in zip(box['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Add `patch.set_alpha(0.5)` to the loop for transparency.

Comment: @n1000 - Note that you can combine calls to "set_<blah>" by using the `set` method.  For example:  `patch.set(facecolor=color, alpha=0.5)`.

Comment: This is great - thank you! I had searched for a clean way to do this for hours.

Comment: Is it possible to set transparency to the facecolor but not to the line of the box ?

Comment: @Ger: For that you'd probably have to do the "same" plot twice: Once with the patch artist, transparent fill, and no lines at all, and then a second time with the line artist (`patch_artist=False`, the default) to get the non-transparent lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [Plotly Python API](https://plot.ly/api/Python). The graph, script, and data for this graph are [here](https://plot.ly/python/script-demos/log-normal-distribution-boxplot-example/).

To control color, you'll want to stipulate a `fillcolor`. Here, it's not set; the default is to fill it. Or, you can make it transparent, by adding `'fillcolor':'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'`. You could also style with the GUI to tweak it.

```
import plotly
py = plotly.plotly(username='username', key='api_key')

from numpy.random import lognormal

x=[0]*1000+[1]*1000+[2]*1000
y=lognormal(0,1,1000).tolist()+lognormal(0,2,1000).tolist()+lognormal(0,3,1000).tolist()
s={'type':'box','jitter':0.5}
l={'title': 'Fun with the Lognormal distribution','yaxis':{'type':'log'}}

py.plot(x,y,style=s,layout=l)
```

Full disclosure: I'm on the Plotly team.

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: what is the advantage of using a webservice-reliant online-system where I have to log in before I can plot? (I thought I’d ask before I vote down as this-is-not-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks Arne. The benefits people usually like are sharing, interactivity, collaboration, and the ability to embed. See an IPython tutorial [here](https://plot.ly/python/matplotlib-to-plotly-tutorial/) for more.

Comment: is it possible to use this without the webservice? (offline)

Comment: @ArneBabenhauserheide, yes. [Here's](https://plot.ly/python/offline/) where to download.