# Python Matplotlib Boxplot Color

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, boxplot

I am trying to make two sets of box plots using Matplotlib. I want each set of box plot filled (and points and whiskers) in a different color. So basically there will be two colors on the plot

My code is below, would be great if you can help make these plots in color. `d0` and `d1` are each list of lists of data. I want the set of box plots made with data in `d0` in one color, and the set of box plots with data in `d1` in another color.

```
plt.boxplot(d0, widths = 0.1)
plt.boxplot(d1, widths = 0.1)
```

Comment: Matplotlib has really helpful [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_color.html) just for this.

Answer (score 64):

To colorize the boxplot, you need to first use the `patch_artist=True` keyword to tell it that the boxes are patches and not just paths. Then you have two main options here:

1. set the color via `...props` keyword argument, e.g.
   `boxprops=dict(facecolor="red")`. For all keyword arguments, refer to [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html)
2. Use the `plt.setp(item, properties)` functionality to set the properties of the boxes, whiskers, fliers, medians, caps.
3. obtain the individual items of the boxes from the returned dictionary and use `item.set_<property>(...)` on them individually. This option is detailed in an answer to the following question: [python matplotlib filled boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289091/python-matplotlib-filled-boxplots), where it allows to change the color of the individual boxes separately.

The complete example, showing options 1 and 2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.normal(0.1, size=(100,6))
data[76:79,:] = np.ones((3,6))+0.2

plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
# option 1, specify props dictionaries
c = "red"
plt.boxplot(data[:,:3], positions=[1,2,3], notch=True, patch_artist=True,
            boxprops=dict(facecolor=c, color=c),
            capprops=dict(color=c),
            whiskerprops=dict(color=c),
            flierprops=dict(color=c, markeredgecolor=c),
            medianprops=dict(color=c),
            )


# option 2, set all colors individually
c2 = "purple"
box1 = plt.boxplot(data[:,::-2]+1, positions=[1.5,2.5,3.5], notch=True, patch_artist=True)
for item in ['boxes', 'whiskers', 'fliers', 'medians', 'caps']:
        plt.setp(box1[item], color=c2)
plt.setp(box1["boxes"], facecolor=c2)
plt.setp(box1["fliers"], markeredgecolor=c2)
            

plt.xlim(0.5,4)
plt.xticks([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. Minor nitpick: "Then you have two main options here" ... and then you list 3 :-) . Which reminds me of the joke "The 4 apostles are the following three: Peter and Paul" (sorry couldn't resist)

Comment: Highlight it again: it is vital to add `patch_artist=True` otherwise the boxes will be `Line2D`s instead of `Patch`s, in which case you can not set face colors to them since those are just lines.

Comment: googled the joke, got a painting.
[x y z w] --> [x y z] --> [x y]

Answer (score 48):

You can change the color of a box plot using `setp` on the returned value from `boxplot()`. This example defines a `box_plot()` function that allows the edge and fill colors to be specified:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def box_plot(data, edge_color, fill_color):
    bp = ax.boxplot(data, patch_artist=True)
    
    for element in ['boxes', 'whiskers', 'fliers', 'means', 'medians', 'caps']:
        plt.setp(bp[element], color=edge_color)

    for patch in bp['boxes']:
        patch.set(facecolor=fill_color)       
        
    return bp
    
example_data1 = [[1,2,0.8], [0.5,2,2], [3,2,1]]
example_data2 = [[5,3, 4], [6,4,3,8], [6,4,9]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bp1 = box_plot(example_data1, 'red', 'tan')
bp2 = box_plot(example_data2, 'blue', 'cyan')
ax.legend([bp1["boxes"][0], bp2["boxes"][0]], ['Data 1', 'Data 2'])
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

This would display as follows:

[image: box plot screenshot]

Comment: You missed the `markeredgecolor` of the fliers. ;-)

Comment: How would you add a label for the blue and a label for the brown boxplots?

Comment: The `bp` returned from the function can be used to make a call to `ax.legend()`, I've updated the example to show you how

Answer (score 13):

This question seems to be similar to that one ([Face pattern for boxes in boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740234/face-pattern-for-boxes-in-boxplots))
I hope this code solves your problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fake data
d0 = [[4.5, 5, 6, 4],[4.5, 5, 6, 4]]
d1 = [[1, 2, 3, 3.3],[1, 2, 3, 3.3]]

# basic plot
bp0 = plt.boxplot(d0, patch_artist=True)
bp1 = plt.boxplot(d1, patch_artist=True)

for box in bp0['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set(color='red', linewidth=2)
    # change fill color
    box.set(facecolor = 'green' )
    # change hatch
    box.set(hatch = '/')

for box in bp1['boxes']:
    box.set(color='blue', linewidth=5)
    box.set(facecolor = 'red' )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you change the fill of individual boxplot? For example, how can I set two different fill colours for `bp0` and `bp1`?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved my problem using the documentation [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_color.html).

Answer (score 5):

## Change the color of a boxplot

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate some random data
data = np.random.randn(200)
d= [data, data]
#plot
box = plt.boxplot(d, showfliers=False)
# change the color of its elements
for _, line_list in box.items():
    for line in line_list:
        line.set_color('r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Weirdly only this solution worked for me. I assume this will be needed for older matplotlib versions. (Version 1.3.1 worked with this).