# Border colour of matplotlib filled boxplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to plot a boxplot which box is filled. I would also like it to have a custom-colour border (different than the whiskers are).

I have found an answer [how to enable filled boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289091/python-matplotlib-filled-boxplots#20291461). Unfortunately the `'edgecolor'` `boxprops` property does not work as expected:

```
plt.boxplot(np.random.normal(size=1000),
            patch_artist=True,
            boxprops={'facecolor': '#AAAAAA',
                      'edgecolor': '#FFCC00'})
```

results with:

[image]

How can I change the border colour of the box alone? Preferably in call to the `plt.boxplot()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the right argument for the `boxprops` is not `edgecolor` but `color`:

```
boxprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1, color='#FFCC00')
```

Other version found, to test:

```
# Create the boxplot
bp = ax.boxplot(data_to_plot)

for box in bp['boxes']:
    # change outline color
    box.set(color='#7570b3', linewidth=2)
    # change fill color
    box.set(facecolor = '#1b9e77' )
```

The key word `color` seems specific to the lines.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to set both `edgecolor` and `facecolor`?

Comment: @abukaj I just did a quick search in the doc of pyplot. From the example given, it should not. Again, I do not have data to test it, nor the time right now. Just check if it works :)

Comment: @abukaj Other version found which tends to show that `color` is specific to the line.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mathieu's answer, sometimes `color` may work (not sure what changes it) and sometimes `edgecolor` will work to change the edges of the boxes.

```
for box in bp['boxes']:
    box.set(edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
```